# AJAX PagingBulletedListExtender - View All

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using the PagingBulletedListExtender with an IndexSize="1". This displays alphanumerics relevant to the list items.

Is there a way of having all items in the collection be displayed?

Comment: Never mind - this has now been accomplished using JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind - this has now been accomplished using JQuery.